# joptionpane and confirmation dialog with yes no buttons

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

This code is working. but the problem is when NO_OPTION is selected then the window is disposed. I want to retain the window when NO_OPTION is selected? can u give any suggestion?

```
    int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "First Row Will Selected As Default!! Do You Want To Close?","Warning",dialogButton);

            if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){ 

                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
                finalOID=(String)table.getModel().getValueAt(row, col);
                System.out.println("cancel clicked first oid:"+finalOID);
                dispose();

                }
```

Comment: As a work around, what you can do is to keep your `JOptionPane` inside a while loop and then check if the **User** has clicked on `YES Option`, only then to break out of that while loop else keep displaying that `JOptionPane`. Though how good this approach is at production environment is questionable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int dialogButton = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "First Row Will Selected As Default!! Do You Want To Close?","Warning",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

This will fulfill the requirement

Answer (score 3):

You may want the `JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION`, illustrated in [*How to Make Dialogs*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).